# How to remove viewport meta tag at one exact breakponit

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have absolutely no idea how to do this and if it's even possible to do this.
So... in CSS I have some media queries breakpoints and I have viewport meta tag in the head of the HTML (`<meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`), but I got this idea when screen width is lower than 800px (`@media screen and (max-width: 800px)`) the viewport tag will be disabled. Is it even possible ??
Or just when screen width is higher than 800px (`@media screen and (min-width: 800px`) viewport meta tag will be active and when it's lower than 800px it will be disabled.

Comment: Why would you do this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Different Meta Tag Based on Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394707/show-different-meta-tag-based-on-device)

Comment: So... mobile version of the  web will be activated under 800px and I don't want there viewport meta tag and I want for example test style by myself with breakpoints.

Comment: Yeah that's it Richard, thank you so much :D